# Pass events onto an element of component VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some component that wraps up an input:

```
<div class="some-component">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

And I'm calling it like so:

```
<some-component v-on:click="dostuff" ref="thatcomponent"></some-component>
```

And then:

```
methods: {
    dostuff(){
        this.$refs.thatcomponent.$el.focus();
    }
}
```

Which focuses the div, where I really want focus to be on the input. This example is my first use-case, but in general **I want to pass all the events called on the component to a specific element within that component**. I don't want to go poking around in the component for the element from the parent component.

Is there a Vue pattern for this?

Comment: If you want to control a specific element from outside the component (i.e. parent), your best bet is probably to simply use a (scoped) slot.

Comment: @TommyF Normally I would agree. In this case, the component is significantly more complex than the example here. Also, really just looking to pass events called against the component onto an element rather than full control.

Comment: you could create a method in thatcomponent that focuses your input and then call it like this.$refs.thatcomponent.focusTheInput()

Comment: @AlvaroCcatamayo good solution for a single event, gets a little tricky for an "all-events" scenario. Maybe I'm just overthinking this though

Comment: Another option is to create a Vue Event Bus and register events on the parent component and listen to them on the child. But you still have to register and fire each event manually on the EventBus and it kind of reverses the expecter relationship of parent-child vue components. But it might work for you,

Comment: Do you actually mean *events*? The example given is not an event, it's a method invocation.

Comment: @skirtle the method shown is an invocation of the focus method on the component's root element. I'd like to capture any invocation of an event on the component from within the component, and pass it instead to a specific element within that component.

Answer (score 2):

Better approach is to add the focus method within the child-component

#### child-component

```html
<div class="child-component">
    <input type="text" ref="theInput" />
</div>
```

```js
// child-component
methods: {
    focus(){
        this.$refs.theInput.focus();
    }
}
```

#### parent-component

```html
<child-component v-on:click="dostuff" ref="childComponent"></child-component>
```

```js
// parent-component
methods: {
    dostuff(){
        this.$refs.childComponent.focus();
    }
}
```

In any case if you want to interact with the child-component's input element from parent-component (useful if you don't have control over the child-component

```js
// parent-component
methods: {
    dostuff(){
        this.$refs.childComponent.$el.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a Vue specific solution to this. You can however manually redirect an event from one element to another by dispatching a new event on the target element.
You will however need a reference to the target element as well as handling all event types manually (there is no wildcard event listener like `foo.addEventListener("*", ...)`

```
clicked(e) {
  var target = document.querySelector("#target");
  target.dispatchEvent(new event.constructor(e.type, e));
}
```

Basic example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-76svb

It is a very unusual pattern though and one should carefully evaluate if this is the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet here is using ref attribute and $refs object. This [section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) in Vuejs Docs might be useful.

***Child Component***

in template:

```
<div class="some-component">
  <input ref="input" type="text" />
</div>
```

in script:

```
methods: {
  ...
  focus() {
    this.$refs.input.focus();
  },
  ...
},
```

***Parent Component***

in template:

You need here to use the `.native` modifier to listen directly to a native event on the root element.

```
<some-component v-on:click.native="dostuff" ref="thatcomponent"></some-component>
```

in script:

```
methods: {
  ...
  dostuff() {
    this.$refs.thatcomponent.focus();
  },
  ...
}
```

**Vuejs Docs**

> $refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within templates or computed properties.

Here is [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-u8fzw) example

I Hope this help.

Comment: I need exactly the opposite. I need to call the listeners en masse, not bind them.

Comment: I guess, you need to clarify more what you want (may be update post). That would be helpful :)